# split the words in one column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, computer-science

I have column in my dataset called Injury Information, This column has information such as `[ skin tear, burning, fracture]`

the data set is like

ID 12434
Injury Information skin tear, burning, fracture

I need the output to be

```
skin tear
burning
fracture
```

I have tried these blew code but I could not get the desired result

```
MedNote = pd.read_csv('ResearchDate.csv')
print( MedNote.head())

#MedNote = MedNote.set_index('Injury Information')

for index, row in MedNote.iterrows():
    
    # Using for loop
   
    for i in MedNote["Injury Information"][index]:
        #for each in i:
            #i.tolist()
             # print(i.str.split(","))
             print(i)
```

Comment: Can you provide a clearer example of what is exactly the input and the expected output?

Comment: Can you describe the layout of your data more clearly, maybe with an example?

Comment: `MedNote['Injury Information'].str.split(',')`

Comment: the exact input is the column  Injury Information, one row of this column has information such as skin tear, burning

Comment: it does work but does not work with MedNote['Injury Information'][index].str.split(',') inspectorG4dget